# When Blurring the content <i-frame> blur is over the content but <H1> blur is under the original header text ASP.NET JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, blur

```
var pageContent = document.getElementById("mainContent"),
        pagecopy = pageContent.cloneNode(true),
        blurryContent = document.getElementById("blurryscroll");
    blurryContent.appendChild(pagecopy);
    window.onscroll = function () {
        blurryContent.scrollTop = window.pageYOffset;

    }
```

Using this script I manage to blur the I-Frame but the H1 text remains "over" the blurred H1.

Why is this happening?

PS. I was following this approach:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/moqZRB

In given example the H1 text is blurred, in my implementation the text gets blurred, but the original non-blurred text remains Over the Blurred one, instead of staying "behind" the blurred text.

Comment: Have you played with "z-index" CSS attributes? Try setting a higher z-index on the blur element

Comment: i will check it straight away.

Comment: no, it seems that changing this value does not affect anything. I never changed z-index. Strange thing is that only text elements of the given div remain on top of the blurred element.

Comment: is there a live demo of your code?

Comment: no, it's still on localhost

Comment: can't help you without seeing code

Comment: which part you would like to see?

Comment: the HTML and JS that generates the whole situation

Comment: i just noticed that     z-index: 1000000000000; gives me more visible blur, but the original text is still over the blurred layeer.